# iPhone: Move UINavigationBar down?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to position the navigation bar below the top of the screen.

I've tried the following in `viewWillAppear`:

```
self.navigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 54.0, 320.0, 426.0);
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0);
```

The problem is it only seems to work the very first time the view is displayed. If you go to another tab, and back, the navigation bar is at the top of the screen. This also happens when the iPhone is rotated.

Should I be trying to adjust the navigation controller frame, or should I instead try to add the navigation controller to another view that is below the top of the screen?

Comment: What about using Interface Builder to do this? It seems I can drag in the navigation bar to any place in a view. I'm not sure if I can hook the navigation controller to this though.

Comment: If I use the UINavigationController in IB, it puts it at the top of the view only.

From the UINavigationController Class Reference:
@property(nonatomic, readonly) UINavigationBar *navigationBar
Discussion
It is permissible to modify the barStyle or translucent properties of the navigation bar but you must never change its frame, bounds, or alpha values directly. To show or hide the navigation bar, you should always do so through the navigation controller by changing its navigationBarHidden property or calling the setNavigationBarHidden:animated: method.

Comment: I ended up using Interface Builder to setup a view with an image and a nav bar with a Navigation Controller in a Tab Bar Controller. Now when I push another view in code, I'm missing the image and nav bar.

Comment: In the xibs, the root view does not actually have the image or nav bar, the same is true of the view I want to push.

Answer (score 4):

Although late, I hope this can still help someone else out. I used Stephens code inside viewDidAppear:animated and the navigation bar stays put upon traveling back to the tab. This allowed me to use a logo above the navigation bar. I used this inside my viewController.

```
    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
self.navigationController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 100.0, 320.0, 426.0); 
self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0); 
[self loadData];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can change the frame by overriding the frame property in viewDidAppear of my custom navigation controller. I also add the navigation controller view to another view that is a subview of the window and make same clipping. Pay attention because in this way you're going to loose the standard calls to every view controllers that will be attached to the navigation controllers. I don't remember if I also used a custom view for my view controllers: maybe yes and with didMoveToSuperview or didMoveToWindow overrided just to emulate the default behaviour. Hope it helps and forgive my english.

Comment: you should show examples IF this worked for you.  Your English is fine.  Your answer doesn't help as much as it could if you put more effort into it.