# How to shift navigation bar position on the screen

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar, statusbar

I have added the following code in my app delegate to create a section below the status bar (as seen in the screenshot after the code)

```
UIWindow *statusWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 20)];
statusWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
statusWindow.hidden = NO;
statusWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.7];
[statusWindow makeKeyAndVisible];
```

[image]

How can I shift the navigation bar downwards so that the black overlay does not overlap with the navigation bar? Essentially, I would like to achieve an effect like that in the screenshot below:

[image]

Any advise or resources on this will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the NavigationController's frame property. Though you should listen to Xav, he speaks the truth. Apple will likely give you the stink eye and put your app in the slow lane of infinite rejection.

Answer (score 4):

There's some advice on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019619/iphone-move-uinavigationbar-down), but one of the comments does point out that you shouldn't really mess with the Navigation Bar directly - worth checking the Apple guidelines to make sure your app isn't going to be rejected out of hand.

Comment: Yeah, don't touch the status bar. Apple will do unpleasant things to your submission path.